# "Wolf's trot broke into a run, wider and wider were the leaps he made" - how to parse this sentence?

Tags: inversion

> Wolf's trot broke into a run, wider and wider were the leaps he made.

<sup>(Source: Jack London, Brown Wolf)</sup>

In this sentence, why does it use inversion "were the leaps he made" or maybe it's a non-restricted attributive clause?

Comment: does it equal "Wolf's trot broke into a run,wider and wider which were the leaps he made"?

Answer (score 1):

The second part could be in normal word order: the leaps he made were wider and wider. The author changed the word order to make his style livelier.

Comment: It's an idiomatic style thing - he could have written 'faster and faster he went' (as opposed to 'He went fast and faster'). You'd only ever use this in writing - you'd almost never speak like this unless relating a story or similar.